# MySQL express a subset of results from a query (i.e. two queries) as a percentage

Tags: mysql

I have a query that returns the number of log messages that match a given search term for each day.

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(logtime, '%d.%m.%y') AS `day`,
  COUNT(DATE_FORMAT(logtime, '%d.%m.%y')) AS `total`
FROM log
WHERE message like '%searchterm%' 
GROUP BY `day` ORDER BY logid DESC
```

What I want to do is fetch the total, i.e. the same query but without the where clause, and display the first total as a percentage of the second total for each day. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ought to do the trick:

```
select tot.day,tot.total,ifnull(s.total,0) as searchTermTotal,
round(100*ifnull(s.total,0)/tot.total,2) as percentage
from
(
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(logtime, '%d.%m.%y') AS `day`, 
  COUNT(DATE_FORMAT(logtime, '%d.%m.%y')) AS `total`
  FROM log 
  GROUP BY `day`
) tot
left join
(
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(logtime, '%d.%m.%y') AS `day`, 
  COUNT(DATE_FORMAT(logtime, '%d.%m.%y')) AS `total`
  FROM log 
  WHERE message like '%searchterm%'
  GROUP BY `day`
) s on s.day = tot.day;
```

Should pick up zero percentages too.